# Chatrooms and Whiteboard Php

Tags: php, chat, whiteboard

I have been building a chat room with a whiteboard feature.
I was able to make specific chat rooms and only people in the specific rooms can see the chat conversations. But when i am using the whiteboard all the people can see the interactions.

If I am drawing in room1 it should only be seen there but unfortunately I can see what i drew in other rooms. How should I limit it only to room1?

any suggestions to solve this problem? Thank you so much..

Comment: Wow there's a lot of guesswork you've left for us here. You'll get better answers if you're more detailed and specific. Leaving *us* with guesswork leaves *you* with questions: How do users get to your chat rooms and whiteboards? Are there IDs? What kind of authentication are you using for your chat-room, and why can you tie the same to your whiteboards? Why can't the whiteboard be incorporated into the chat room? Are either of these features third-party apps? Are the "drawings" from other white boards being shown in your "Room 1" whiteboard? Or can room 1's whiteboard be seen in Chat Room 2?

Comment: Sorry for the vague question sir its my first time posting here. Before users can enter the chat rooms they have to provide a room password.. when entering the room it will load the chat and whiteboard feature.. we just used a third party whiteboard app. we are only using one file for the whiteboard feature which is called for every room. both ways sir drawings from room1 can be seen in room2 and drawings from room2 can be seen in room1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should do something like only one chat room at a time. To view another chat room you have to remove your current session and add a new one of another room. Even worse you should make account per chat room! Why do you want to use that? Could you explain in more detail?

Comment: we are successfully handling a plain multiple chat room at a same time. but if we add the whiteboard feature in the chat rooms and draw something it can be seen by users in different rooms which should not happen.